# I want to show and share my React.js app on portfolio

Tags: github, publish, portfolio

I do not know how to create a preview so others may see my react app. I have created. I would like to have a link to it on my portfolio.  . I have posted screenshots and uploaded the files to Github https://github.com/courtneyangotti/PlayWall. I am looking for jobs so everything I can show helps of course!

I have posted screenshots and uploaded the files to Github https://github.com/courtneyangotti/PlayWall.

I just want to have a link for my portfolio

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is to deploy your react app, you could do it thanks to [heroku](https://www.heroku.com).
Use the [Heroku Buildpack for Create React App](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack).
You can find instructions in [Deploying React with Zero Configuration](https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration).